# Can't rake db:migrate because of unset variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm actually configuring a gitorious at home and I've a problem with rake.

I've got to do this `rake db:migrate` but when I do it i've got this message :

> rake aborted! 
>   A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.action_controller.session = { :key => "_myapp_session", :secret => "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters" } in config/environment.rb

So I edited config/environment.rb by adding this line :

> config.action_controller.session = { :key => "gitorious", :secret => "foobar" }

I also try to edit config/environments/production.rb. But problem still exists.

My env is set to production

> export RAILS_ENV=production

I'm running on Debian Squeeze with rake version 0.8.7.

Edit : My password is longer than 30chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,

The session secret needs to be at least 30 characters, the example you posted is less than 30 characters. A tool to assist in generating random keys is http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/. You can specify that you want a random key with the length of 30 characters.

Comment: Sorry, my password "foobar" was for the example. I already use http://strongpasswordgenerator.com ^^

Thanks you :) :)

Comment: No problem, you could try `rake db:migrate --trace --verbose`, also does `script/server` or `rails server` work?

Comment: I do NOT believe it. I just put a tabulation before the "config.action_controller.session...." line and it's OKAY !!! 5 hours to discover this...

I got the same kind of problem before but I change tabulation by spaces in an yml file.

So, thank you very much christiangeek :)